# Disable tableview cell button on tap in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have the button working correctly, I just can't figure out how to disable it on tap. I'm not sure if I can reference it from the addSomething(sender: UIButton) function like I reference the sender.tag.
Any idea? Thanks for any help.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExploreCell

    // Configure the cell...
    myCell.configureCell(teams[indexPath.row])

    myCell.addSomethingButton.tag = indexPath.row
    myCell.addSomethingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.addSomething), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    myCell.addSomethingButton.enabled = true

    //disable cell clicking
    myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    return myCell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need to do is to store all tapped buttons in an array to check whether the button of this tag (current indexPath.row) has been tapped:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var tappedButtonsTags = [Int]()

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExploreCell

        // Configure the cell...
        myCell.configureCell(teams[indexPath.row])

        myCell.addSomethingButton.tag = indexPath.row

        // here is the check:
        if tappedButtonsTags.contains(indexPath.row) {
            myCell.addSomethingButton.enabled = false
        } else {
            myCell.addSomethingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.addSomething), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            myCell.addSomethingButton.enabled = true
        }

        //disable cell clicking
        myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

        return myCell
    }

    // I just Implemented this for demonstration purposes, you can merge this one with yours :)
    func addSomething(button: UIButton) {
        tappedButtonsTags.append(button.tag)
        tableView.reloadData()
        // ...
    }
}
```

I Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for working it all out but after putting it in place it seems to only do your check when the tableview loads not after the button is clicked as well.

Comment: it's simple, answer has been edited by adding "tableView.reloadData()" to the buttons' target :)

Comment: Ahh, thank you! That worked great! I'm also looping through an array before to check the database for any already added and they worked great togther.